# How to upgrade bitcoind (Bitcoin Core) in Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, ppa, bitcoin

I would like to know all the options that exist to upgrade bitcoind (PPA or manually).

I am running a full Bitcoin node and it's important for me to keep the last available version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin to your system's Software Sources.

https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin

Or compile from source.  Also, be aware running a version of bitcoind is considered 'voting' for it.  At this time as long as you are running 10 or newer you should be fine.

Comment: Sorry for the n00b question (and not just googling it), but what makes it an 'untrusted' PPA?

Answer (score 4):

1. `bitcoin-cli stop`
2. `sudo apt-get update` (assuming you have `bitcoin` installed via the Ubuntu [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin))
3. `sudo apt-get upgrade bitcoind`

If you're using QT just swap `bitcoin-qt` for `bitcoind` since that's the name of the package you're upgrading.

Comment: I see that the other answer got the green tick - tried that - did not work.  This is the one that worked for me - clear and easy to execute.  Thanks mecampbellsoup - much appreciated.